# Merge data frames for Cohen's kappa

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I'm trying to analyze some date using **R** but I'm not very familiar with **R** (yet) and therefore I'm totally stuck.

What I try to do is manipulate my input data so I can use it to calculate Cohen's Kappa.
Now the problem is, that for rater_1, I have several ratings for some of the items and I need to select one. If rater_1 has given the same rate on an item as rater_2, then this rating should be chosen, if not any rating of the list can be used.

I tried

```
unique(merge(rater_1, rater_2, all.x=TRUE))
```

which brings me close, but if the ratings between the two raters diverge, only one is kept.

So, my question is, how do I get from

```
item rating_1
1    3
2    5
3    4 

item rating_2
1    2
1    3
2    4
2    1
2    2
3    4 
3    2
```

to

```
item rating_1 rating_2
1    3         3
2    5         4
3    4         4
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some fancy ways to do this, but I thought it might be helpful to combine a few basic techniques to accomplish this task. Usually, in your question, you should include some easy way to generate your data, like this:

```
# Create some sample data
set.seed(1)
id<-rep(1:50)
rater_1<-sample(1:5,50,replace=TRUE)
df1<-data.frame(id,rater_1)

id<-rep(1:50,each=2)
rater_2<-sample(1:5,100,replace=TRUE)
df2<-data.frame(id,rater_2)
```

Now, here is one simple technique for doing this.

```
# Merge together the data frames.
all.merged<-merge(df1,df2)
#   id rater_1 rater_2
# 1  1       2       3
# 2  1       2       5
# 3  2       2       3
# 4  2       2       2
# 5  3       3       1
# 6  3       3       1

# Find the ones that are equal.
same.rating<-all.merged[all.merged$rater_2==all.merged$rater_1,]
# Consider id 44, sometimes they match twice.
# So remove duplicates.
same.rating<-same.rating[!duplicated(same.rating),]
# Find the ones that never matched.
not.same.rating<-all.merged[!(all.merged$id %in% same.rating$id),]
# Pick one. I chose to pick the maximum.
picked.rating<-aggregate(rater_2~id+rater_1,not.same.rating,max)
# Stick the two together.
result<-rbind(same.rating,picked.rating)
result<-result[order(result$id),] # Sort

#     id rater_1 rater_2
# 27   1       2       5
# 4    2       2       2
# 33   3       3       1
# 44   4       5       3
# 281  5       2       4
# 11   6       5       5
```

---

A fancy way to do this would be like this:

```
same.or.random<-function(x) {
  matched<-which.min(x$rater_1==x$rater_2)
  if(length(matched)>0) x[matched,]
  else x[sample(1:nrow(x),1),]
}
do.call(rbind,by(merge(df1,df2),id,same.or.random))
```

Comment: If you like it, you can check the arrow to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing even two ways of approaching this. For now, I will try to understand the first version... :)
What I don't understand is the line with the aggregate function. What does
    rater_2~id+rater_1
mean?
I tried to look it up, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Look at the examples in `?aggregate`, specifically at the ones under `## Formulas...`. Essentially, this means, for every combination of `id` and `rater_1` in `not.same.rating`, find the `max` value of `rater_2`.